# Game on a graph Hall’s marriage theorem

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Let $G$ by a bipartite graph with parts $X,Y$ both of size $n$. Two players alternately name vertices. P1 names a vertex $a_1$ in X. Then P2 names a vertex $b_1$ in Y which has an edge to $a_1$. Then P1 names a vertex $a_2$ in X which has an edge to $b_1$. And so on. No repetition is allowed and whoever can’t name vertex loses. Show that P2 has a winning strategy when there is a perfect matching in $G$ and P1 has a winning strategy if there isn’t a perfect matching.

I think this should somehow relate to Hall’s marriage theorem, but I’m really lost. Please help.

Comment: First show that if there is a perfect matching, P2 could use it to win. For the other half, it's a matter of preference/style as to how to approach it, but I prefer the contrapositive: If I had a winning strategy for P2, can I use that to confirm that there is a perfect matching? Since you're asking for "help", it might be best for you to either post a solution (if you can take things from here) as an answer or to edit your question with your progress and a specific question (one time only). Math Stackexchange isn't really suited to a back-and-forth.